# Sharepoint javascript:OpenPopUpPage Is not being displayed well on Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, master-page, page-layout, css, popup

I have added and code snippet to my team site home page to display a pop up when clicking on a link:-

```
<li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://192.168.8.221/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726',1000,1000);" unselectable="on">Camera One</a></li>
<li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://192.168.8.95/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=736',1200,1200);" unselectable="on">Camera Two</a></li>
```

The pop-up will be displayed well , with the right width and height on IE and firefox,:-

[image]

while it will not be displayed well on chrome and safari. And the pop-up will have wrong width and height on safari and chrome, and it will be very narrow as follow:-

[image]

So any idea what is causing this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i was not passing the call back function, so i modify my javascript code to be

```
javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://192.168.8.221/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726',null,1000,1000)
```

and now it is being displayed well on all browsers